# Как изменить цвет иконки на кнопке FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, material-design

Есть кнопка:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:onClick="onClick2"

    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
```

Для нее в colors.xml прописано

```
    <color name="colorAccent">#0b93c4</color>
```

Выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, что бы карандашик был белым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная иконка устанавливается атрибутом `android:src`. Изменить цвет Вы ей не сможете. Надо лишь установить новую картинку.
Могу посоветовать отличный плагин, который содержит в себе полный пакет иконок.
Скачать можно [отсюда](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7647?pr=)

Потом как подрубите его, жмите правой кнопкой по любому пэкэйджу, выбираете new->Material design icon. После чего откроется окошко, в названии вбиваете edit(чтобы выбрать иконку карандаша), студия вам предложит варианты изображений, выбираем то которое нам подходит, цвет, размер, жмем "ОК". В наши папки drawable упадут нарезанные иконки. Далее в FAB заполняете атрибут `android:src` путем к иконке и видим профит=)

Answer (score 4):

В коде просто пропишите:

```
fab.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой фильтр 
`fab.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));`, ресурс тот же.

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: фильтры идентичны, наверно где то должны быть нули)

Comment: @ermak0ff, точно, видать не скопировалась строчка во второй раз, спасибо, поправил.